# If a current is flowing up a vertical wire why will a larger current be required to get the direction of deflection on west side versus the east side?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

I've been posed this question by my professor. This is the entire question, and for context I'm assuming he is referring to deflection of a galvanometer, not a compass.

Even so, I don't see why there should be a difference of deflection magnitude between the west side and east side. I thought the magnetic field is circling the wire, so it should deflect at the same magnitude no matter what side it is on.

Comment: The deflection of what? The question is incomplete as stated. What is the complete question, as posed by the professor?

Comment: Edited, I'm assuming a galvanometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we ignore the northward magnetic field of our planet, then magnetic field around a long straight wire is symmetric.  For an upward current, using the right hand rule, the produced field on the east side of the wire points northward.  The produced field on the west side points southward.  When we add the northward planetary field to this, the total magnetic field is stronger on the east side of the upward current than on the west side.

Comment: Thx, I had a feeling he might have been referencing the earth's magnetic field.